# openid4java I/O Transport Error using Google OpenID and restricting to Google Apps

Tags: google-apps, google-openid, openid4java

I'm using openid4java and Google as my OpenID federation. However, I would like to restrict the login to a specific Google App domain.

I'm currently the endpoint:
    https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com

The error I get when trying to verify the response is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: example.com
```

root cause:

```
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisException: 0x704: I/O transport error: example.com
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:478)
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:248)
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.verifyDiscovered2(ConsumerManager.java:1693)
org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.verifyDiscovered(ConsumerManager.java:1521)
org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.verify(ConsumerManager.java:1156)
com.workday.qna.openid.OpenIDHelpers.verifyResponse(OpenIDHelpers.java:87)
com.workday.qna.controllers.OAuthContoller.getOAuthCallback(OAuthContoller.java:19)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: That's quite old.. but did you find any resolution you might recall now?